# Removing duplicates using set

Tags: python, set

Basically, I want to do this with iteration from a lst in to a set and the printing it back to list. The problem I get is that I can't iterate through set.add(item). set.add() was perfectly fine when applying one value outside a loop but I can't get it to work inside a loop.

Using this function I am able to remove duplicates.

```
remove_duplicates(numbers):
    lst = []
    for i in numbers:
        if i not in lst:
            lst.append(i)
    return lst
```

However, I want to be able to do something like this.

Here is how far I was able to come.

```
lst = { }
lsto = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 7, 5]

for item in lsto:
    lst.add(item)

print(lst)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why loop when you can just do `list(set(lsto))`?

Comment: does order matter because your two code snippets will give different results ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean this,

```
>>> lsto = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 7, 5]
>>> list(set(lsto))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

`set(lsto)` turns the iterable `lsto` into set which in-turn remove the duplicate elements. By again turning the set to list will give you a list at final.

Answer (score 1):

To match the first logic and keep order you can use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) :

```
from collections import OrderedDict
lsto = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 7, 5]

print(OrderedDict().fromkeys(lsto).keys())
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

The set by chance gives you the same order but sets are *unordered* collections so you cannot rely on getting any order.

Comment: plus 1! you should not accuse people of down voting! i think i can like you! the best work is leave comment !